# How to fix gulp task - css task is working non-stop?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I'm starting a new gulp project. There is browser sync and when I run `gulp` or `gulp watch`, changing something in scss/css files it's run css task in non-stop, even if I'm not duing something with css it's Starting and Finished non-stop. If I try to chnage something in js, it added also this task and the working non-stop both...

```
var themename = 'humescores';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    // Prepare and optimize code etc
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    image = require('gulp-image'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),

    // Only work with new or updated files
    newer = require('gulp-newer'),

    // Name of working theme folder
    root = '../' + themename + '/',
    scss = root + 'sass/',
    js = root + 'js/',
    img = root + 'images/',
    languages = root + 'languages/';


// CSS via Sass and Autoprefixer
gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src(scss + '{style.scss,rtl.scss}')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'expanded', 
        indentType: 'tab',
        indentWidth: '1'
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(postcss([
        autoprefixer('last 2 versions', '> 1%')
    ]))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write(scss + 'maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(root));
});

// Optimize images through gulp-image
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src(img + 'RAW/**/*.{jpg,JPG,png}')
    .pipe(newer(img))
    .pipe(image())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(img));
});

// JavaScript
gulp.task('javascript', function() {
    return gulp.src([js + '*.js'])
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(js));
});


// Watch everything
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    browserSync.init({ 
        open: 'external',
        proxy: 'localhost-site.com',
        port: 8080
    });
    gulp.watch([root + '**/*.css', root + '**/*.scss' ], gulp.series('css'));
    gulp.watch(js + '**/*.js', gulp.parallel('javascript'));
    gulp.watch(img + 'RAW/**/*.{jpg,JPG,png}', gulp.parallel('images'));
    gulp.watch(root + '**/*').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});


// Default task (runs at initiation: gulp --verbose)
gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('watch'));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9yyR.jpg)

Comment: maybe you are writing in the same directory that you are watching? then it would trigger itself everytime it writes the css.

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger itself"?

Comment: example: when you watch the folder `abc` and then you generate a file from scss and put it under `abc\generated.css` then your watch task will see that the `generated.css` file was changed and will run the tasks again, creating `abc\generated.css` again which will then trigger the watch task ....

Comment: Yes, gulp watching the folder where all these files are... How I need to save files then?

Answer (score 0):

you use one `src` directory where you watch the files and one `dist` (or whatever you call it) folder where your generated files are placed.

Or you can for example generate the file in `/css/styles.css` and put all scss files in `css/scss/....` and only watch the `css/scss` folder.